# String with the class name and get the Class.class

Tags: java, reflection

I've a string containing the class name but I want to get the Xyz.class

Like this:

```
String className = "Xyz"

public Class getTheClass(className){

(what do I need to do here?)

return Xyz.class;
}
```

I know it has to do with reflection but it is not working the way I've been trying to do which is like this:

```
public Class getObjectClass(String className) throws Exception
{
    Class c = Class.forName(className);
    return c.getClass();
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
java.lang.Class
```

And I want `Xyz.class`

Comment: Just `return c;` - don't call `getClass()`.

Comment: David Wallace, this is really the answer. Would you like to add this as an answer so that it may be accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call `getClass()` here, because `c` is already a `Class`.

```
public Class getObjectClass(String className) throws Exception {
    Class c = Class.forName(className);
    return c;
}
```

If you use `getClass()`, then you're getting the class of a `Class` object, which is, of course, `java.lang.Class`.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
return c;
```

Instead of

```
return c.getClass();
```